# Angular 4 routing not works when invoke direct url path

Tags: angular, redirect, angular2-routing

I have an angular 4 apps with many routes. 
My issue is really simple to understand. All routing works fine inside the app.
The problem come out when I go directly to a specific url
Ex. 
 Base url app is http://myserver/
and when I invoke the url above I see my home page (http://myserver/home)
if I invoke a url of a specific path (ex. http://myserver/anotherpathpage) the app redirects me always on the home.

Any idea? 
I'm using html5 location strategy (no hash in the url) and my base href is "/"

Thanks a lot
F

Comment: the problem's seem that whenever going to specific path (ex:  http://myserver/anotherpathpage), always redirect to home page? Also, expected result showing specific page content?

Comment: Yes it's the problem I have. When I call a specific path or also reload a page always go on home page

Answer (score 0):

You can try config something like that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
      path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule'
    },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Using **pathMatch: 'full'** to restrict only root path that should be redirected to home page. Others paths will be routed by layout module.

I hope to help you.